# How to solve functions of type $f(g(t))$

Tags: functions

Please can someone guide me how to solve this type of problem?

If $f$ is the function $f(x) = 1 +x +x^2$, find $f(g(t))$.

I've never solved them before. I just need an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f$ acts on **variable** $x$.  That means that $x$ can be anything at all.  $f(banana)=1+banana+(banana)^2$.  In this case, we want to take $x=g(t)$, so substitute that in for $x$ in the function $f$.

Comment: Look for my upcoming book "Math with Fruit", out next month on Amazon...

Comment: So the answer is: $1 + gt +g^2t^2$?

Comment: Close; $g(t)$ is the function $g$ applied to $t$.  It is not the "product" of $g$ and $t$.  So the answer is $1+g(t)+(g(t))^2$.

Answer (score 2):

in your case, what is x?  It is simply g(t).

So $$f(g(t))=1+g(t)+[g(t)]^2$$

Comment: So, $g(t)$ is not a function here?

Comment: it is a function, but it could be ANY function, just like x is a number, but it could be ANY number.  It is only asking you for f(g(t)) but your g(t) is unknown.  As @vadim123 pointed out, f is just an operator and we are given what f(x) is, so whatever is in the (x) goes where x is.  Since g(t) is in f, we get $f(g(t))=1+g(t)+[g(t)]^2$

Comment: your question doesn't give you what g(t) is so we treat it as if it were just a variable like x or y, or banana.

Comment: Banana is a very appreciable argument :)

Comment: Does not give expected results with "rabbits",

  
    f(rabbits)=1+rabbits+(rabbits)^2 = many many rabbits.